# Second array will not increment after repeating for loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, if-statement, kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and am trying to compare the elements of two arrays by seeing which array has the greater element. The arrays are created via user input. The error that I am having is that when I repeat the second for loop (inner loop), which contains the contents of the second array, it will not increment to the next element of the second array unlike the first for loop. So if `a = {1,2}` and `b = {2,1}`, `a` would increment through both 1 and 2, but `b` would stay at 2 through both iterations of the loop. Here is my function that is giving me a problem:

```
    fun practiceCompareArray(a: Array<Int>, b: Array<Int>): Array<Int> {
        var j: Array<Int>
        var aPoints = 0
        var bPoints = 0

        for (x:Int in a) {
--------->  for (y: Int in b) {
                if (x > y) {
                    aPoints++
                } else if (x < y) {
                    bPoints++
               break
            }
        }

        j = arrayOf(aPoints, bPoints)

        return j
    }
```

The for loop with the arrow is giving me the problem. I think it is because of the break statement at the end of the inner loop. Do I even need the inner loop to compare each array? Any help or documentation would be helpful.

Comment: Do you want to compare the arrays element-wise? I.e. the first elements of both, then the second of both, etc? In that case have a look at `zip`.

Comment: That is correct. The first elements of both, then the second of both, etc. I will take a look at zip and get back to you afterwards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that both array have the same length and you want to compare them elementwise you could do something like:

```
fun practiceCompareArray(a: Array<Int>, b: Array<Int>): Array<Int> {
    var aPoints = 0
    var bPoints = 0

    for ((x,y) in a.zip(b)) {
        if (x>y) {
            aPoints ++
        } else {
            bPoints ++
        }
    }
    return arrayOf(aPoints, bPoints)
}
```

or in a more functional style

```
fun practiceCompareArray(a: Array<Int>, b: Array<Int>): Array<Int> {
    val (aPoints, bPoints) = a.zip(b)
      .fold(Pair(0,0), {(aScore, bScore), (x,y) -> 
         if (x > y) Pair(aScore + 1, bScore) else Pair(aScore, bScore + 1)})

    return arrayOf(aPoints, bPoints)
}
```